# Android application crashes when run in my phone from the android studio

Tags: android

I am a beginner in programming and trying to work on an sample project in android studio but my application crashes when i run it in my phone.
Please help me. What can be done?
I am getting this error when i checked in logcat.

```
01-06 13:18:20.778 13471-13471/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.hof_university.chethan.chatmessenger, PID: 13471
                                                   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.hof_university.chethan.chatmessenger-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:753)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:621)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:631)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                       at com.hof_university.chethan.chatmessenger.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6177)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:188)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1530)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editMessage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMessageE);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages");
}

public void sendButtonClicked(View view){
    final String messageValue = editMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageValue)){
        final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
        newPost.child("content").setValue(messageValue);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: share your **`build.gradle`** with question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail code and error... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

and this

```
buildToolsVersion 27.0.2
compileSdkVersion 27.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the official document, getFont this method is added after the `api 27`, and need to add `com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0` in `build.gradle` file. It belongs to `ResourcesCompat`

[ResourcesCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getFont(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.FontCallback,%20android.os.Handler))

[android doc getFont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYZl4.png)